How to build a homemade diy motor generator
I am doing a school project and it would be great to have some help. I have built a small generator using a pringles can and enameled copper wire, but when I spin the magnet inside, the voltmeter I am using does not show any constant increase in AC voltage. The meter is not the problem as it is brand new and was around $80. I have tried spinning both with the direction of the wires an

meter is not the problem ... but how you are using it may be a problem ... you have provided alost zero information about your project, and about what you are doing

Post pictures of your generator.

when I spin the magnet inside [a coil] I can imagine many ways to spin a magnet inside a coil, and few do significantly change the flow through it. Does the angle between the magnet's field and the coils axis change?

No voltage? Even a single wire loop should catch something measurable if a magnet was moved nearby. Possible reasons:

The movements of your magnet do not cause remarkable flux variations through the coil. You for example spin a magnet inside the coil. The effects of the south and north magnetic poles cancel each other or the motion is directed so that no flux variations were caused even in case you had magnetic monopoles (not for sale nor available otherwise in our world)
You expect something dramatic like 200 volts from a system which generates for example less than a volt
The frequency of your AC is low, say one or 2 Hz and you measure with a meter which expects tens of hertzes to show something else than zero. Turn to DC measurements to see something in that case

